# htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes()) in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a screen that parse json, my problem is it display html code instead of pure text.
 How can I implement htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes()) in flutter?

Thank you
[Please view this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjcWR.png)

Comment: Probably your json is has html string in it. Please check the json

Comment: yes Midhun how can I eliminate in flutter?